# How to Display 3 month(i.e., January,Febuary,March) calendar of year 2020

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have recently started learning Linux(Ubuntu) Commands, I'm confused how to display 3 month calendar.

I have tried `cal -y 2019 -A3` command but this command is Displaying first three months of 2020 after the calendar of 2019.

```
unix@unix:~$ cal -y 2019 -A3
                            2019
      January               February               March
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
       1  2  3  4  5                  1  2                  1  2
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12   3  4  5  6  7  8  9   3  4  5  6  7  8  9
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  10 11 12 13 14 15 16  10 11 12 13 14 15 16
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  17 18 19 20 21 22 23  17 18 19 20 21 22 23
27 28 29 30 31        24 25 26 27 28        24 25 26 27 28 29 30
                                            31

       April                  May                   June
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
    1  2  3  4  5  6            1  2  3  4                     1
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13   5  6  7  8  9 10 11   2  3  4  5  6  7  8
14 15 16 17 18 19 20  12 13 14 15 16 17 18   9 10 11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25 26 27  19 20 21 22 23 24 25  16 17 18 19 20 21 22
28 29 30              26 27 28 29 30 31     23 24 25 26 27 28 29
                                            30

        July                 August              September
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
    1  2  3  4  5  6               1  2  3   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13   4  5  6  7  8  9 10   8  9 10 11 12 13 14
14 15 16 17 18 19 20  11 12 13 14 15 16 17  15 16 17 18 19 20 21
21 22 23 24 25 26 27  18 19 20 21 22 23 24  22 23 24 25 26 27 28
28 29 30 31           25 26 27 28 29 30 31  29 30


      October               November              December
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
       1  2  3  4  5                  1  2   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12   3  4  5  6  7  8  9   8  9 10 11 12 13 14
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  10 11 12 13 14 15 16  15 16 17 18 19 20 21
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  17 18 19 20 21 22 23  22 23 24 25 26 27 28
27 28 29 30 31        24 25 26 27 28 29 30  29 30 31


                            2020
      January               February               March
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4                     1   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11   2  3  4  5  6  7  8   8  9 10 11 12 13 14
12 13 14 15 16 17 18   9 10 11 12 13 14 15  15 16 17 18 19 20 21
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  16 17 18 19 20 21 22  22 23 24 25 26 27 28
26 27 28 29 30 31     23 24 25 26 27 28 29  29 30 31
```

And I want the Output like this:

```
                              2020
      January               February               March
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4                     1   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11   2  3  4  5  6  7  8   8  9 10 11 12 13 14
12 13 14 15 16 17 18   9 10 11 12 13 14 15  15 16 17 18 19 20 21
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  16 17 18 19 20 21 22  22 23 24 25 26 27 28
26 27 28 29 30 31     23 24 25 26 27 28 29  29 30 31
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cal` utility options are significantly different between Debian/Ubuntu and RHEL/Fedora.

On Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ cal jan 2020 -A2
                         2020
     January               February               March     
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4                     1   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11   2  3  4  5  6  7  8   8  9 10 11 12 13 14
12 13 14 15 16 17 18   9 10 11 12 13 14 15  15 16 17 18 19 20 21
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  16 17 18 19 20 21 22  22 23 24 25 26 27 28
26 27 28 29 30 31     23 24 25 26 27 28 29  29 30 31
```

On RHEL/Fedora:

```
$ cal -n 3 jan 2000
    January 2020          February 2020          March 2020     
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4                     1   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11   2  3  4  5  6  7  8   8  9 10 11 12 13 14
12 13 14 15 16 17 18   9 10 11 12 13 14 15  15 16 17 18 19 20 21
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  16 17 18 19 20 21 22  22 23 24 25 26 27 28
26 27 28 29 30 31     23 24 25 26 27 28 29  29 30 31            
                                                                
$
```